# basic use of QMap

Tags: qt, qmap

This is my first time using QMap and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <QMap>
QMap<QString, int> name_sec_age;
name_sec_age.insert("willy", 593381460);
```

my errors are: 
   "unknown type name 'name_sec_age'"
and "expected unqualified id"

I'm using Qt Creator 4.0 with Qt 5.6 on a mac.
Side note: the run button on Qt Creator isn't available. To run my app I build it and then open the app from its path in finder. rather annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run code in the wild like that, it needs to be in a function.

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main() {
    QMap<QString, int> name_sec_age;

    name_sec_age.insert("willy", 593381460);
    qDebug() << name_sec_age;
}
```

Comment: @Life4ants then accept either mine or Kuba Ober's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your setup must be messed up somehow. Perhaps you'll have more luck by installing macports and using Qt/Qt Creator from there.

The following compiles just fine for me under Qt 5.5.1:

```
#include <QMap>

int main() {
   QMap<QString, int> name_sec_age;
   name_sec_age.insert("willy", 593381460);
}
```